# Play sound and animate element as result of if else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am building a game for my javascript class and have hit a brick wall. The basic concept is each result should trigger an animation and play a sound. Where I have my else statement, I can get the animation to fire, but when I drop in the audio to test, it will not work. Any help is appreciated.

```
function gameOver(){
if (userChoice == d1 && chosenCup == d2) {
    alert("Congrats, You have Won!");
    } else if (chosenCup == d2 && userChoice != d1) {
        alert("You almost did it.");
    } else {
        var audio = $("#sound1")[0];
        audio.play();
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the audio to play when?

Comment: I want to play a different sound and display a corresponding image for each statement. pseudo example:                                                       if (userChoice == d1 && chosenCup == d2) {
    playSong1,showImage1;
    } else if (chosenCup == d2 && userChoice != d1) {
        playSong2,showImage2;
    } else {
        playSong3,showImage3;
    }